# How can you not sum the averages?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence

So the main problem is that I would like to show the average numbers per Week numbers. But I don't know why but it sums up all the averages, and not just average the averages.

My current DAX formula:

```
    Average = 
AVERAGEX(
FILTER('Code',Code[Code_name] = "Failure"),
CALCULATE([Time])
)
```

Where Time is another Measure.

[image: Picture about the matrix]

you can see that calculating the average by ID works, but if you collapse the matrix it shows weird numbers per week number.
Any advice?

Comment: what is the code for [Time]?

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the "Show value as" in the visualization.

By default it is sum, try average of your measure.

[image]

[image]